# Oracle: How to Rewrite UNION for Performance

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have ORACLE UNION SQL which is working fine.
Can you please help me find alternatives of rewriting the SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  select app_id, org_id, emp_id, name, name_id,
  from TableA AAA, TableC CCC, TableB BBB
  where BBB.ID=CCC.ID
  AND AAA.ID=BBB.ID
UNION
  select app_id, org_id, emp_id, name, name_id,
  from TableA AAA, TableC CCC,TableD DDD 
  where DDD.ID=CCC.ID
  AND AAA.ID=DDD.ID
) MYTABLE
WHERE MYTABLE.app_id = '1234'
AND MYTABLE.org_id = '5678';
```

I tried to convert the UNION SQL into a Scalar query as some suggests but I'm getting error: "too many values"

```
SELECT 
(select app_id, org_id, emp_id, name, name_id,
from TableA AAA, TableC CCC, TableB BBB
where BBB.ID=CCC.ID
and AAA.ID=BBB.ID
and app_id = '1234'
and org_id = '5678'
) q1,

(select app_id, org_id, emp_id, name, name_id,
from TableA AAA, TableC CCC,TableD DDD 
where DDD.ID=CCC.ID
and AAA.ID=DDD.ID
and app_id = '1234'
and org_id = '5678'
) q2
) from dual;
```

What may be the problem in my Scalar query?
Or are there other ways I can rewrite this query with better performance?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You can't have more than one value in a column using a sub query within your select like that. Have you tried doing an outer join on tables D & B in a single select?

Comment: Can you expose which tables app_id and org_id come from?  If they are from AAA and CCC, then you could limit those in a subquery prior to the joins to BBB and DDD.  The union is expensive because it has to filter out distinct values (versus a union all, which doesn't care).  If you can limit the number of records that have to be grouped/sorted, it will have a dramatic impact on the number of logical IOs.

Comment: If both queries don't return duplicates to filter out, you can use `union all`. `union all` will leave duplicates untouched, while `union` basically gets all `distinct` values of the result, which is obviously an extra processing step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start would be to do the filtering in the individual selects. Limit the data set you are working with as  early as possible. What you are doing now is get all the rows from the tables, get the unique values from that big data set (you are using UNION not UNION ALL), filter the records.

```
  select app_id, org_id, emp_id, name, name_id,
  from TableA AAA, TableC CCC, TableB BBB
  where BBB.ID=CCC.ID
  AND AAA.ID=BBB.ID
  AND app_id = '1234'
  AND org_id = '5678'
  UNION
  select app_id, org_id, emp_id, name, name_id,
  from TableA AAA, TableC CCC,TableD DDD 
  where DDD.ID=CCC.ID
  AND AAA.ID=DDD.ID
  AND app_id = '1234'
  AND org_id = '5678';
```

PS your selects are syntactically incorrect. The select list ends with a comma.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT app_id, org_id, emp_id, name, name_id 
FROM 
(
SELECT app_id, org_id, emp_id, name, name_id
FROM TableA AAA
JOIN TableB BBB ON AAA.ID = BBB.ID
JOIN TableC CCC ON BBB.ID = CCC.ID

UNION

SELECT app_id, org_id, emp_id, name, name_id 
FROM TableA AAA
JOIN TableC CCC ON AAA.ID = CCC.ID
JOIN TableD DDD ON CCC.ID = DDD.ID 
) MYTABLE

WHERE MYTABLE.app_id = '1234'
AND 
MYTABLE.org_id = '5678';
```

Comment: I don't get how this is different from the original query, other than moving the joins from the where clause to an ANSI join syntax